# Запрос mySQL UPDATE выдает ошибку если количество символов больше 2000

Tags: php, mysql, sql

При помощи данного запроса обновляю информацию в бд

`$sql = "UPDATE car SET  title='$title',  Text='$text'  WHERE id=11";`

Все работает, но если количество символов не превышает 2000, если же больше тогда выдает ошибку

"Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'portfolios Provide bank account signatory services for clients world-wide Open b' at line 1"

Как исправить?

Comment: тип колонки с текстом у вас какой?

Comment: @СергейМишин  text

Comment: А ошибку выдаёт на любом тексте с длиной больше 200 символов? А то может быть на одном конкретном и проблема в каком-нибудь экранировании? Делали ли вы запрос с подготовленными переменными (используя mysqli/pdo)?

Comment: @СергейМишин ошибку выдает на всех формах при отправке текста, если более 2000 символов. Пробовал с заранее подготовленным переменными , все равно не работает

Comment: Во-первых какая у вас кодировка? Во-вторых есть ли в отправляемом тексте кавычки?

Comment: @NikolajSarry Да, есть кавычки, без них заработало) Но как их игнорировать, при отправке данных?

Comment: Обрабатывать входящую строку на php чтобы они экранировались.

Comment: @NikolajSarry а  при подготовленных выражениях, текст с кавычками некорректно будет вставляться?

Comment: @СергейМишин скорее всего нет, так как мы засовываем необработанные данные. Даже при условии подготовленных выражений строку которую хотим загнать в базу надо обработать от спец.символов, которые повлияют на структуру запроса. Так как подготовленные выражения все равно развернутся в чистый sql. И если он встретит кавычку или еще какой спец.символ, то он подумает, что это чего-то не то.

Comment: юзайте подготовленные с биндингом параметров. не надо никакой доп. обработки и экранирования. не слушайте оратора постом выше.